# spark scala on yarn cluster csv export

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

I have a 5 node cluster, YARN is deployed. 2 Namenodes and 3 Datanodes. While my code is submitted in spark. I'm trying to export data to csv, but when i do that, the data gets exported to 2 datanodes and both will have different content inside the export folder. One will have _SUCCESS file and the other will have the exported csv (part-*). My application ends up having a blank path because sometimes the node which has _SUCCESS file and the node where the application is running are same, but the actual csv is in another node. Also sometimes the _SUCCESS file is not created but the part-*.csv is created but in another node, in which case if the application is not running in the same node again, i end up with a blank path again.I'm using the following way:

dataframe.coalesce(1).write.option("header","true").csv(path)

Comment: What is the value of ur path?

Comment: file:///<absolute path in the linux system>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of file:///
Why are you not giving a hdfs/s3 location?

When u give a local path, data is stored on the worker nodes! You probably have the data on 2 nodes instead of 3 because there wud be 2 partitions.

Comment: The data i'm trying to export is in cassandra, and after processing it i'm trying to export. The export needs to be done in Linux filesystem because UI needs access to the file.

Comment: I'm getting only one part-* file because i used coalesce. But the problem is it gets created on the node where the application is not running. So, if datanode3 is running the application, export folder is created on datanode1 and datanode3. datenode1 contains the part-*.csv file and datanode3 contains _SUCCESS. the absolute path is same in both the nodes. Because the application is running in datanode3, it returns the localhost of the node with file location but that location doesn't contain the file, datanode1 does.

Comment: I feel both datanode1 and datanode3 are running 1 executor each because of which they have the tarhet directory created. How are u certain that only datanode3 is running d executor?

Comment: when i give <yarn application -list> only datanode3 ip is shown against that application. Also when I open the namenode:8088 interface, the logs and containers are shown in datanode3.